# batch_set results in TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback

Tags: 9, batch-operations

I am trying to set a batch from a confirmation form. When it is submitted, this is the code:

```
$operations = [];

$operations[] = [
  [UpdateEntity::class, 'execute'],
  ['field_group']
];

$batch = array(
  'title' => t('Updating...'),
  'operations' => $operations,
  'init_message'     => t('Commencing'),
  'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
  'error_message'    => t('An error occurred during processing'),
);

batch_set($batch);
```

But I get this error immediately, I have cleared cache, restarted, checked namespaces and filenames, no avail:

```
TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class "Drupal\mymodule\Batch\UpdateEntity" not found in _batch_process() (line 295 of /var/www/html/web/core/includes/batch.inc)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to replace `UpdateEntity::class` with `Drupal\mymodule\Batch\UpdateEntity`?

Comment: Yes, tried both. Oddly enough it works in another project.

Comment: And is `UpdateEntity()` is defined with only one parameter?

Comment: Yes. Moved the same code to a .module file and it did not error out at all.

Comment: I cannot spot any error. Drupal core uses similar code, for example in [`ConfigSync.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21config%21src%21Form%21ConfigSync.php/9.3.x). There could be something wrong in the code that isn't shown. I take the class is referenced in a `use` statement and `UpdateEntity` is the correct class name.

Comment: It might be a fatal in the batch class that I can't reach with xdebug (gives up immediately). I'll give it another look.